# Помогите разобраться с DialogFragment в android

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

Стоит задача - реализовать в приложении `alertDialog` по нажатию на экран. В принципе это я сделал, оно работает:

```
mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng latLng) {

     AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
     View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_isparking, null);
     Button yes = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnYes);
     Button no = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnNo);
}
```

Но есть проблема - при повороте экрана диалог пропадает. Как я понял, этого можно избежать, если использовать `DialogFragment`. Я сделал отдельный класс, за образец взял код [отсюда](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) и [отсюда](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/180-urok-110-android-3-fragments-dialogfragment-dialog.html)

Получилось так:

```
public class Dialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static Dialog newInstance(int title) {
        Dialog frag = new Dialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    public android.app.Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("Title!")
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) this)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) this)
            .setMessage(R.string.message_text);
        return adb.create();
    }

    void showDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = Dialog.newInstance(1);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

Потом в `main activity` пытался сделать так:

```
public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng latLng) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.showDialog();
}
```

При нажатии на экран приложение крашится, андроид студия пишет:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.app.FragmentTransaction
>   android.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object
>   reference

Помогите исправить ситуацию. Мой первый вопрос здесь, надеюсь, мысль донес верно.

Comment: лучше всего не использовать имя класса `Dialog`, так как такое имя уже есть в API Android и легко запутаться в импортах. Если фантазия отказывает, назовите его хоть `MyDialog`

Comment: Спасибо, учту замечание

Answer (score 2):

Уберите метод `void showDialog()` из диалога, а в активити напишите:

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
 dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Дайте диалогу осмысленное имя.

Comment: Спасибо, эту проблему благодаря вам устранил!

Comment: Правда, в моем сами понимаете каком коде всплыла новая беда, ошибка такая: java.lang.ClassCastException: Dialog cannot be cast to android.content.DialogInterface$OnClickListener, не нравится третья строчка отсюда (про title):  public android.app.Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Title!")

Comment: @ИльяСергеев, вы пытаетесь прикастить диалог свой к `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`, но диалог имплементит `View.OnClickListener`, замените `implements View.OnClickListener`, на `implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

showDialog() должен быть в активити и подаваться туда должен getSupportFragmentManager(), если диалог на фрагменте то getChildFragmentManager()